# malloc crashes in loop but fine outside of loop

Tags: c, loops, struct, crash, malloc

I have the following procedure that's causing my program to crash:

```
void parseLinear(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML *xmlFile){

// Set up Linear Property Here
struct daastLinear *Linear;
Linear = (struct daastLinear *) malloc (sizeof(struct daastLinear));

// Assign  Property
xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->Creatives->data->linear = Linear;

// ***** THIS IS FINE HERE
struct daastMediaFile *newMediaFile;
newMediaFile = (struct daastMediaFile *) malloc (sizeof(struct daastMediaFile));

do {

    // ***** PROGRAM CRASHES IF I PUT IT HERE INSTEAD
    //struct daastMediaFile *newMediaFile;
    //newMediaFile = (struct daastMediaFile *) malloc (sizeof(struct daastMediaFile));


    if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("Duration")) == 0){

        char *nodeValue = (char *) node->children->content;
        xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->Creatives->data->linear->duration = malloc (sizeof(char));
        strcpy (xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->Creatives->data->linear->duration, nodeValue);

    } else if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("MediaFiles")) == 0){
        //
        parseMediaFiles(doc,node->children,xmlFile);
    }
} while ((node = node->next));

}
```

The problem is with the lines:

```
struct daastMediaFile *newMediaFile;
newMediaFile = (struct daastMediaFile *) malloc (sizeof(struct daastMediaFile));
```

If I put these outside of the loop, the program works fine, but if I place them inside the loop, it just crashes and I can't see any error logs.

Does anyone know what is happening here?

***EDIT and possible fix?***
This is the original struct of the MediaFile:

```
//THIS CAUSES A CRASH
struct daastMediaFile {
    char *id;
    char *delivery;
    char *type;
    char *url;
    char *bitRate;
};
```

But adding an int variable, it then works?

```
//THIS CAUSES A CRASH
struct daastMediaFile {
    char *id;
    char *delivery;
    char *type;
    char *url;
    char *bitRate;
    int MediaID;
};
```

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: putting it inside the loop means you are allocating memory again and again. Do you really wanna do that?

Comment: See my fix above, the loop should only occur just once, but it may have two or three times so it's not a big issue. It doesn't really explain why it never worked in the first place, the loop only iterates once with my test data anyway

Comment: @GlennCooper, if the problem has stopped manifesting for you then it is unlikely to be because of your change to the members of `struct daastMediaFile`.  `malloc()` neither knows or cares about the members of your struct; it just allocates the number of bytes requested.

Comment: For us to determine what's really going on, we'll need to see an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Any suggestion in this case? This is strange behaviour

Comment: "Any suggestion in this case?" How about dropping `newMediaFile` and the `malloc()` call altogether, since you never use the allocated result.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I never put the rest of the code in to make it simpler, regardless of whether it's is used or not, this should not crash

Comment: @GlennCooper, evidently either your intuition for what should not crash or your analysis of where the crash occurs is faulty.  Otherwise, you would have no question.  This is why we ask for an MCVE.

Comment: And because the process of producing an MCVE sometimes leads you to discover and solve the problem for yourself.

Comment: @GlennCooper the only "suggestion" I have is to heed the answers!

Answer (score 1):

```
xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->Creatives->data->linear->duration = malloc (sizeof(char));
```

this allocates memory for only ONE character. In C, it may hold only an empty string (since the last char is '\0'). Is it what you intended?

Comment: You completely missed the point of the crash, but if you see my fix above, it appears to work now. On the note of the duration - this also works fine and is able to store more what I need

Comment: @GlennCooper so have you *bodged* a fix that "works"?

Comment: @GlennCooper it is not uncommon to think that because you move one line that alters the behaviour then that is the line at fault. As this answer said, you allocated one byte of memory and then copy a string into that space. Far from "missing the point" this answer has found a definite fault in your code.

Comment: `xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->Creatives->data->linear->duration = malloc (strlen(nodeValue)+1);`. Or you could use `xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->Creatives->data->linear->duration = strdup(nodeValue);` if your C runtime library has `strdup` (you wouldn't need the `strcpy` call in this case, as `strdup` combines the `malloc` and `strcpy`).

Answer (score -1):

```
//Outside the loop
typedef struct daastMediaFile *daastMediaFiles;
daastMediaFiles newMediaFile;

//In the loop, if needed. free() is important in end of loop
newMediaFile = malloc(sizeof *newMediaFile);

...

free(newMediaFile);
```